# Create List of Maps from JSON

Tags: groovy

I'm grabbing variables from JSON and trying to figure out how to put them into a list of maps.

I want the map to be as follows:

```
[[
   "taskId": 12345, 
   "Name":"User1", 
   "UserId":"abc123"
 ], [
   "taskId": 000000, 
   "Name":"User2", 
   "UserId":"123abc"
]]
```

Some code example:

```
    Map activitiTasks = [:]

        tasksJson.data.each { taskObject ->
            Map tsksObj = [:]

            String taskId = getTaskId()
            tsksObj.put("taskId", taskId)

            String name = getUserName()
            tsksObj.put("Name", name)

            String userId = getUserId()
            tsksObj.put("userId", userId)

            tsksObj.put("userId", username)
            activitiTasks.put(tsksObj)
        }
```

Comment: If you have the JSON then it is easy to convert to the desired data structure of List of Maps by using [JsonSlurper](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html). You would not need to manually parse the JSON to lists/maps.

Comment: I received the JSON, I need to move it to a LIST OF MAPS.  This example is for me to see how you want loop through JSON (variable called tasksJson in code) and put that into list of maps.

Comment: I may be missing something you are trying to do but my point is mentioned here is [this example](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/04/groovy-goodness-parse-json-with.html). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Update following  Opal remark (thanks :))
Let’s assume your input json text looks like

```
[
    {
        "taskId": "0234",
        "userId": "abc023",
        "name": "User0"
    },
    {
        "taskId": "1234",
        "userId": "abc123",
        "name": "User1"
    },
    {
        "taskId": "2234",
        "userId": "abc223",
        "name": "User2"
    }
]
```

The following code using JsonSlurper as suggested by dmahapatro will do the job.
The internal object are automatically returned as map

```
def tasksJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonlistText)
println activitiTasks
println (activitiTasks[0] instanceof Map)
```

The console will display

[[name:User0, taskId:0234, userId:abc023], [name:User1, taskId:1234, userId:abc123], [name:User2, taskId:2234, userId:abc223]]
**true**

Comment: `def tasksJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonlistText)` - this is enough to get list of maps.

Answer (score 0):

My data was being sent back as a array of characters, therefore in my controller I imported grails.converters.JSON.

Once I did that I returned by ArrayList of Maps back as a JSON by doing the following command.  I am using this as a AJAX call so use render instead of return.  The call I used is shown in testController.groovy (render lists as JSON).

lists in the example below is an ArrayList(), that gets Maps added to it through a loop.

Index.gsp

```
function getItems(start) {
   $.ajax({
      url: '(${g.createLink(controller:'test', action:'getItems'})}',
      data: {startValue: start},
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
         $(data).each(function() {
            console.debug($(this)[0].itemId);
         }
      }     
   }
}
```

testController.groovy

```
class testController {
   def index() {}
   def getItems() {
      def strStartVal = params.startValue ?: "0"
      def intStartVal = Integer.parseInt(strStartVal)
      def lists = dataService.getItemsFromQueue(intStartVal)
      render lists as JSON
   }
}
```

dataService.groovy

```
getItemsFromQueue(int start) {
   def items = getItemsFromDatabase("DBNAME", 20, start)
   List lists = new ArrayList()

   items.data.each { taskObject ->
      Map model = [:]

      ......Some Code Goes Here.......

      lists.add(model)
   }
   return lists
}
```